# Two transaction with same receipt numbers

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a payment system for which i generate a receipt number (which work in increments) for each transaction. Process is like when user hit pay, then request goes to server who fetch latest receipt number from database increment it by 1 then immediately save it to database for further transactions and so on. Receipt numbers are being generated in format xx000001, where xx are characters.

**Problem**:- Sometimes two or more transaction are processing with same receipt number.

**Possible scenario**:- The scenario i came up with is like - Suppose someone press hit then server fetch latest receipt number, while server is doing increment a new transaction came in and fetch the same receipt number as the previous one and both of them do the increment & got the same receipt number to process with.

Any help would be highly appreciated !!!

Thanks

Comment: Execute your queries in a transaction. See http://php.net/manual/mysqli.begin-transaction.php

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the classical issue: you have no thread-safety! Concurrent requests (and a http servers *typically* processes concurrent requests need to be implemented such that the critical steps (which might create collisions) are *prevented* to be executed in parallel.

You have multiple options to approach the issue:

1. create thread safety in your logic

take care to create some form of lock that prevents multiple processes to be processed at once, though only for the critical step, here the incrementation of that counter. `php` does not offer something like java's `synchronized` keyword which does exactly that, so you have to implement that yourself. Easiest would be either a classical unix like file system based lockfile: a process that needs to have unique access requests the lock file. If it does *not* yet exists it is generated (typially with the processes process id as content) and the process performs its action until it has finished and takes care to release the lock again / remove the lock file again. Only then a second process can create that file, until then it get's blocked (hangs). Retries to obtain the unique log can be implemented either by a primitive polling strategy, so the lock obtaining request os tried again every few hundred milliseconds, or you implement a queuing system which can also take care to keep the requesting processes in a defined order of processing and which can take care of cleanup procedures like removing stale lock files (after something has crashed or is outdated).

2. use semaphores for locking

same as above, but you rely on php's "semaphores" to implement the locking itself: 
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.sem.php

3. use table locking inside the database

same as above, but you rely on the locking feature of the database engine (depends on the type of database engine you use). This is faster and easier to implement in the end, since you need to interact with the database anyway.

4. use stored procedures

you can also move the critical parts into stored procedures inside the database. This allows to perform the required steps inside a single database transaction which per definition is guaranteed to either perform completely or not at all. So you generate a new ID as a primary key in your counter table. When you then use that key for further queries (inserts) *in the same transaction* you perform in the database_, then you are safe since any attempt to commit the transaction of it leads to a collision of the primary key will get rejected by the database. In that case you can simply start the process over again.

5. use the `sync` PECL extension

There is a PECL extension for `php` which does offer something comparable to java's `synchronized` keyword:

http://php.net/manual/en/threaded.synchronized.php

This allows to use a locking mechanism right inside your php code. But you need to have a single process for that to work, so it depends on your worker setup inside the http server environment how to do that. If you rely on a thread-based worker model for php (all php requests processed in a single process but multiple threads), then you are ready to go. If however you use a multi-process worker model (as typically done using the "prefork php module" or a "fast cgi container"), then you need to implement an additional single process based lock manager (like the queue manager mentioned above). So something like a microservice you use internally. Does not sound to me like it is worth the hassle :-)